# Rule for taking sum and compare fails

Tags: prolog

My question is about a problem representing a list in Prolog.
I have two knowledge bases and I need to show products and price by person that they could buy, not all products by person. The condition it's by the money could to spend by each person.

```
%. The knowledge base of elements and their prices.

product (cookies, 3).
product (coca_cola, 2).
product (potatoes, 2).
product (tomatoes, 4).
product (meat, 6).
product (fish, 4).

%. The knowledge base of people and their spending money.

person (aria, 10).
person (Robert, 16).
person (Jim, 20).

% The rule I need to show name's person and the products and it's price, that each person 
% can buy with the money they have.
% Once I get this, I need her to propose me products at random, 
% until I reach the money of each person.


show_products(X,Y):-product(X,Y).
show_persons(X,Y):-person(X,Y).

% With this I show all persons with all products price.
show_product_spend(X,Y,Z):-person(X,_),product(Y,Z).

% Apend is not sufficiently instantiated in that rule...
show_product_2(X,Y,Z):-person(X,Money), product(Y,Z), Apend is Z + Apend, Apend < Money.

% But if it is instantiated. Add is Z+Add, it do not add, compare.
% and Add < Money return false.
instantiate(0).
show_product_3(X,Y,Z):-person(X,Money), product(Y,Z), instantiate(Add), Add is Z + Add, Add < Money.
```

I have searched several days and I did not reached a solution. I'm desperate.
I learned about lists helps somewhat, however the problem with lists is similar.
To control with variables that the accumulated price of the products does not exceed the limit of the money of each person and thus not continue showing more products.
Prolog variables cannot modify its data, this is the problem.
Found this possible solution to implement in my problem:

```
allowed_input (1). % your
allowed_input (2). % knowledge
allowed_input (3). %        base

restricted_sum (A, B, C): -
    allowed_input (A),% test user input's
    allowed_input (B),% validity
    C is A + B. % test the result
```

but it doesn't work for me and this shows a combination of results.

I hope someone would help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Please note that variables start with a capital letter, so the facts

```
person (Robert, 16).
person (Jim, 20).
```

do not state any information about a person named Robert or Jim but the following would:

```
person(robert, 16).
person(jim, 20).
```

Also my SWI prolog does not allow spaces between the predicate name and the brackets.

You really should learn about lists, because these will solve your problem. You know it is a list when you see these brackets: `[...]`.  A list is often used by separating it into a first element `H` (head element) and a rest list `T`(tail) written as `[H|T]`, example:

```
?- L=[a,b,c], L=[H|C].
L = [a, b, c],
H = a,
C = [b, c].
```

---

Ok, if I understood correctly you want for each persons all the food he or she can buy. This would look something like this:

```
spend_money_on_products(P,L)
```

where `P` is a person and `L` is a list of food and their prices which the person can afford.
I will put my code here and explain it step by step.

```
getproducts(M,In,[(Prod,Amount)|Out]):-
    product(Prod,Amount), % guess product
    \+ member(Prod,In), % no duplicates
    Amount =< M, % enough money
    Mnew is M - Amount, % subtract
    getproducts(Mnew,[Prod|In],Out).
getproducts(_, _, []).

spend_money_on_products(P,L):-
    person(P,M),
    getproducts(M,[],L).
```

So at first we neet to know how much money `M` a person `P` has: `person(P,M)`. Easy. Now we are not interested in the person `P` anymore and can focus on the money `M`. Now we can ask for items `L` which we can buy for `M`, starting with an empty basket (empty List `[]`):

```
getproducts(M,[],L)
```

Now we need to define what to do with `getproducts/3`. This predicate has 3 arguments: Money left, a list representing the shopping basket and a list representing the filled shopping basket with prices. At first we guess a product `Prod` with price `Amount` (`product(Prod,Amount)`). Then we check if this item is not already in the basket (`\+ member(Prod,In)`, `\+/2` can be read as not). If you are not interested in duplicates in you list you can delete this line.

Next is a check if there is enough money for this item (`Amount =< M`). If so you can subtract this amount (`Mnew is M - Amount`). Now you have a different amount of money (`Mnew`) and you should add a product to your basket by putting it as the head element of a list (`[Prod|In]`). Now you can ask again this question with the new amount and the new basket `getproducts(Mnew,[Prod|In],Out)`.

Once there are not items left to be found, you return an empty list (`getproducts(_, _, []).`). The order of the actions is determined by their position, so it first tries to match every product by the first rule and if it does not find any product it will just say the return basket is empty.

We forgot one thing: the return basket is not filled yet. This is done by "collecting" all the bought items when they have matched (first line): `getproducts(M,In,[(Prod,Amount)|Out])`. Once you successfully found an item `Prod` for the price `Amount`, you put it as head element in your shopping basket.

Lets test it:

```
?- spend_money_on_products(aria,L).
L = [(cookies,3), (coca_cola,2), (potatoes,2)] ;
L = [(cookies,3), (coca_cola,2), (tomatoes,4)] ;
L = [(cookies,3), (coca_cola,2), (fish,4)] ;
L = [(cookies,3), (coca_cola,2)] ;
L = [(cookies,3), (potatoes,2), (coca_cola,2)] ;
...
```

Looks good. Please note that every line is a different shopping basket. They are separated by a semicolon `;`. Also an empty basket is ok as well.

Comment: You have been very helpful. I appreciate it a lot.
I didn't think I could make this use of lists.
I only need you to give me one line, not several combinations.
Researching, I have found that using: 
`code`
once (spend_money_on_products(aria,L)).
`code`
It can help. Also cut with "!" but I have to review how it will be used.
Thank you very much to you.
Greetings.

Comment: @plasben20 try to be comfy with lists and recursion first. cuts are a bit confusing, so be sure to understand the basics before using them.

Comment: All right, I will.
Thank you so much for everything!